# Geany: How to find and count?

Tags: linux, text-editor, geany

I know of a rather powerful feature in Notepad++ where you can search the entire document for a specific string and count its number of occurrences. That is all in the Find function (Ctrl+F).

E.g. Data:
Error reading file
Error reading file
Error in line #3
Error reading file
Error in line #5

Find & Count*: "line" = 2

I could not seem to find this* function in Geany. If there is already a plugin for this, please share it. Otherwise, please share on how would one do the same -- without switching to another editor.

Comment: I don't understand what you a looking for. Please go into more detail. Also it might sound like a feature request, which is off topic here.

Comment: @frlan Thanks for responding. I assure you that this is not a feature request. I'm looking for, within the Geany application, how to count for total specific word. In the following string "Hey diddle diddle, The cat and the fiddle, The cow jumped over the moon. The little dog laughed to see such fun and the dish ran away with the spoon." There are 6 occurrences for the word "the", 2 for "diddle", 2 for "and". I want to know if Geany can do that. If so, how?

Comment: Well. Actually there is no feature currently in Geany that is creating some histrogram of your data. You have to setup your own e.g. by using the send selection to command

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can check message output. After searching just check "Messages" tab.

[image]

Comment: This is it! Thank you.

Comment: This did not work for me. Messages tab is empty. I'm on Ubuntu 22.04.1 with Geany 1.38. Searching XML document.